# is it possible that I can move contents of 2 lvm disks to one big lvm

Tags: lvm

Is it possible that I can move contents of 2 LVM disks to one big LVM, Say for example, I have 5 LVMs created on 2 PV disks xvdb1 and xvdd1.

Is it possible to merge them both to say xvdf1? I have 5 partitions on these 5 LVMs. (Each partition on each LVM)

Will there be any disruption or corruption in the application data on the disks if I move them with **pvmove**?

Comment: Did you accidentally submit this question before you were finished writing it?  It kind of trails off in the middle of a sentence there.  Anyway, take a look at `pvmove`.

Comment: I tried it..and worked. Only doubt I have is, if an application is running over the disks, will that be affected some how? Will a pvmove affect any files or its locations or alignment?

Answer (score 4):

The `pvmove` tool is what you want here.  It is able to seamlessly and safely migrate the extents of a logical volume between physical volumes (disks or partitions).  There is no availability impact, however significant disk I/O is performed, so depending on your disk subsystem's performance capacity, there may be some service degradation during the move.